# Vim how to change the cursor from char block to pre pipe/line

Tags: linux, unix-shell, vim

Not sure what the terminology is for it but on Vim the 'cursor' is always like an insert/replace cursor instead of the blinking line cursor I'm used to in other gui editors. Is there any way to change this when in insert mode?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777950/vim-change-block-cursor-when-in-insert-mode).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42118416/52817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `vim` inside a shell, you should configure the cursor style in your terminal emulator. Even if you do so, Vim can't toggle the cursor style on-the-fly. That's a limitation of the terminal itself.

If you are talking about the graphical version of vim, called `gvim` (or `macvim`), then look at Nupraptor answer.

BTW, I think this question is better suited to the Superuser.com site.

Comment: I found the option in iterm

Answer (score 1):

This plugin for vim will actually change the cursor on the fly in iterm (and tmux)

It has a few bugs if you're in tmux, but works great outside of it: https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about gvim, then you can change the cursor to an 'I' when in insert mode with:

```
set guicursor=i:ver100-iCursor
```

**EDIT:**
The 'i' is for *insert mode*. You can also define it for 'n', 'v', 'c' or 'a' (*normal mode*, *visual mode*, *command mode* or *all modes*, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

maybe it would be enough to change the color acording to which mode you were in? If so I use.
"CURSOR COLOUR When in terminal
" change the color of the cursor to white in command mode,and orange in insert mode

```
if &term =~ "xterm\\|rxvt"
:silent !echo -ne "\033]12;white\007"
let &t_SI = "\033]12;orange\007"
let &t_EI = "\033]12;white\007"
autocmd VimLeave * :!echo -ne "\033]12;white\007"
endif
```